# NullPointerException on orientation change

Tags: android, view, drawerlayout

I am implementing the new `DrawerLayout` in a new project. My code is almost verbatim from the `DrawerLayout` guide and works find until I change orientation. What happens on orientation change is that any View set via `findViewById` is returning null. In the below code Both `mDrawerList` and `mDrawerLayout` are null on orientation change, but not when Activity is first opened.

I check for null value to prevent the `NullPointerException` but I receive another warning in LogCat:

```
05-22 20:56:08.375: W/PhoneWindow(16528): Previously focused view reported id 2130968626 during save, but can't be found during restore.
```

The Activity now loads but the DrawerLayout will no longer slide out from the left as before. What's wrong here?

This is the method that my onCreate calls.

```
public void initializeDrawer() {

    // Get list of menu items from array resource
    mDrawerItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    if (mDrawerList == null)
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the listview
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerItems));

    // Set the lists click listener
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // Set up the action bar toggle listener to get the draw moving
    if (mDrawerLayout == null)
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        //     onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        //     onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // Attach the listener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: On orientation change your Activity gets destroyed & recreated. Do you re-initialize e.g. mDrawerList in onCreate()?

Comment: Hi there, Yes as mentioned above the initializeDrawer() method is called in OnCreate()

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that. But if that is the case, why do you have the null checks in place? mDrawerList and mDrawerLayout should be null in any case then, not only on re-orientation. Or do you initialize them at some other place as well?

Comment: I added the null checks because, in debugging mDrawerList is NOT null until it runs the assignment line. It runs onCreate twice because the actual code in initializeDrawer() is in the super class which my activity inherits from

Comment: I am not sure if that helps with your actual problem, but it sounds strange to me that initializeDrawer() gets called twice. If the method is in the super class then it should be called via onCreate only there, right? Why does the subclass call initializeDrawer again (it should only call super() which in turn calls initializeDrawer). Again I am not sure if that helps, but maybe the listeners get messed up if you call initializeDrawer twice.

Comment: You're right. The super call is already there so I will remove the new call.

Comment: @henning77 I know this is extremely old but please make your comment a reply and I will mark it as an answer...Going through my old questions!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange to me that initializeDrawer() gets called twice.

If the method is in the super class then it should be called via onCreate only there. Why does the subclass call initializeDrawer again (it should only call super() which in turn calls initializeDrawer).

Your problem might be caused because the listeners get messed up when you call initializeDrawer twice.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following to your `Activity`:

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```